# iOS - Authenticated access

Tags: ios, authentication, app-store

I have an application which content should only be accessible once the user enters a password at the start.

Anybody knows if the Apple Store validation will be a problem since they won't be able to access any of the app functionality without the password?

Let me know if this isn't the right place to ask and I'll move the question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you habe to give them demo userid nd password...

-->statement in apple guidelines

Incomplete Information
Enter all of the details needed to review your app in the App Review Information section of iTunes Connect. If some features require signing in, provide a valid demo account username and password. If there are special configurations to set, include the specifics. If features require an environment that is hard to replicate or require specific hardware, be prepared to provide a demo video or the hardware. Also, please make sure your contact information is complete and up-to-date
source

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/

Comment: Thanks user3923716 - I think @JGrice is correct by pointing to the point 2.22 in the review guidelines. In my case the access will be arbitrary, therefore only users with a password will be able to see the information (confidential).

Answer (score 0):

This will not be a problem. There is a specific method to supply the app reviewers with temporary accounts to access content and features during the review process.

From the docs:

Providing App Review Information
If your app requires specific settings, user account information, or special instructions, include these details in the App Review Information section of iTunes Connect. If you don't include this information, the app review process may be delayed and your app could be rejected. For more details on providing App Review Information, read the iTunes Connect Developer Guide.

Comment: Thanks Woodstock - I think @JGrice is correct by pointing to the point 2.22 in the review guidelines. In my case the access will be arbitrary, therefore only users with a password will be able to see the information (confidential).

Answer (score 0):

If the app allows the user to create an account and requires the user to login to use it, then it is fine. If only people given this password are ever allowed to access your app, then it will more than likely be rejected.

The only restriction to users that Apple explicitly states in the [review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) is:

"2.22 Apps that arbitrarily restrict which users may use the App, such as by location or carrier, may be rejected."

Comment: Thanks @JGrice, in my case the app wouldn't allow sign in. I am just looking for a way to limit the people who can access the information as it is confidential.